# config.xml on system not same as Jenkins UI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have edited the config.xml file within the jobs directory on the Jenkins system:

```
$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/myjob/config.xml.
```

I expect the changes to be reflected on the Jenkins UI when I go to configure on the job page: https://my-jenkins-system/job/myjob/configure

But this does not happen. It works the other way around, i.e if i edit in UI, I see the changes in config.xml.

Is the one displayed on UI a cached file? or Am I doing something wrong or is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 6):

After modifying the data in `config.xml` you need to select the below option

**Jenkins --> Manage Jenkins --> Reload Configuration from Disk**

in your Jenkins to see the changes in UI.

Comment: Is there any risk in doing "Reload Configuration from Disk"??

Comment: What to do if you are using the UI to make changes but pressing save only updates the .xml file on disk and NOT the user interface in Jenkins?? It still displays the old config even though it was actually modified on disk....